# How can I change the alert dialog item text color?

Tags: android, dialog, alert

[whatch the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHGNu.jpg)

code:

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/activeRed</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: for more customize better to use custom layout and inflate it

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8K4Jo7B

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : declare colorAccent and text color to style like this

```
    <style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
<item name="colorAccent">@color/yourColor</item>
      <item   name="android:textColor">@color/teal_200</item>
  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
   <item name="android:background">@color/colorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

Step 2: assign this style to your dialog like this:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
 AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, 
 R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
```

Have  fun.

Comment: Try it but not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this -
STEP 1-

```
val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialog)
            builder.setTitle("THIS IS TEST")
            builder.setPositiveButton(
                "Yes"
            ) { _, _ -> Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Yes") }
            builder.setNegativeButton(
                "No"
            ) { _, _ -> Log.e("LOG_TAG", "No") }
            builder.create()
            builder.show()
```

STEP 2- Add in style.xml

```
<style name="AlertDialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#C51162</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#11EA21</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Try it but not working